# Ubuntu Blender 2.8 wont detect Nvidia GPU

Tags: gpu, linux

I have re installed drivers twice, and re installed blender, watched a couple of tutorials but i cant seem to get the option to select my GPU in CUDA >n< ,it is a 1050 mobile, im testing ubuntu on a laptop in case i wanna move to linux on my pc.

My first attempt was to download and install drivers manually, I followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0JhBPB6_Vr4) but couldnt get pass the Nvidia X server part thingy, where it would allow me to see my Nvidia settings, after i finished the tutorial and got no result i thought of asking here in case someone was able to help ._.

so umm.. help :(

Comment: Did you manage to fix this? I'm having the same issue

Comment: @user43712 yes but actually no.. solution was to install a different distro called "Pop!_os" it is an ubuntu based distro, you can kinda call it clone. but yea this has everything ubuntu offers and better, its more user friendly and in my experience it was ready to use the second i installed it.

Comment: I might give Pop a go, thanks :)

Comment: If anyone's ever figured out a solution to this, I'd love to hear. Pop!_OS is great (especially with nvidia), but I'm on void (for now) and prefer it (for now). I'm able to get CUDA by running the tarball of off blenders's website (can't use the one in the package manager) but not OptiX nor OpenCL.